# Sabre's SOAP method for multicity search

Tags: soap, sabre

Fellow Techies, I am implementing Sabre's SOAP api for flight bookings. I wish to know if there is any SOAP method available for Multi City search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below link with the Alternate Airport Shop API:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/alternate_airport_shop