# Sabre Multi-city API

Tags: sabre

Usually, what I see in multi-city flight search it takes Origin, Destination and Departure date. Example https://www.onetravel.com/flights/multi-city

I am trying to find the API to do this kind of search in Sabre but couldn't find one.

I have seen an answer given on this question: [Sabre's SOAP method for multicity search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968146/sabres-soap-method-for-multicity-search), but the api given in the answer is not taking departure time for all stops.

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you further elaborate this? In BFM one has to add departure times in all segments.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering I actually didn't know that BFM can be used for multi-city search. I thought it was for one-way and round-trip. This APi is working fine for me https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Answer (score 0):

For Multi city just add all segment This is for REST Api BFM Seach

//For 1 City

```
          {
            "RPH": "1",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-22T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DAC"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            }
        }
```

//For 2 City

```
        {
            "RPH": "1",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-22T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DAC"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "2",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-26T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JFK"
            }
        }
```

//For 3 City

```
       {
            "RPH": "1",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-22T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DAC"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "2",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-26T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JFK"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "3",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-28T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JFK"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            }
        }
```

//For 4 City

```
         {
            "RPH": "1",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-22T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DAC"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "CCU"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "2",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-26T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "CCU"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "KTM"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "3",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-04-28T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "KTM"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            }
        }, {
            "RPH": "4",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2022-05-02T00:00:00",
            "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DAC"
            }
        }
```

For 5 City You wont get any Itenary and Getting Its Very Rare Case